# Overloading a function with the same require conditions

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

The following code ([online](https://godbolt.org/z/R-wuoE))

```
template<int m> struct A {
    void f(A<m> const& that) const requires m > 1 { }
    void f(A<1> const& that) const requires m > 1 { }
};

int main(){
    A<2> a;
    a.f(a);
    return 1;
}
```

gives the error *`void A<m>::f(const A<1>&) const requires m > 1` [with `int m = 1`] cannot be overloaded with `void A<m>::f(const A<m>&) const requires m > 1` [with `int m = 1`]*.

Why is this not allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is "`[with int m = 1]`". When `m` is 1, you get these two "overloads"

```
void f(A<1> const& that) const requires 1 > 1 { }
void f(A<1> const& that) const requires 1 > 1 { }
```

The unsatisfied requires clause doesn't "undeclare" an overload. It only makes the overload not participate in overload resolution. The overload is still declared, and in your case you get the exact same definition twice for `m = 1`.

A simple workaround is to make the signatures different, thus gaining two overloads

```
void f(A<m> const& that) const requires m > 1 { }
void f(A<1> const& that, int = 0) const requires m > 1 { }
```

Comment: That's interesting to know. Do you know what the background behind this decision is? I mean if it does not meet the requirements why should it be declared?

Comment: @t.niese - It's nothing new, it's just SFINAE (extended a bit) with a better syntax. I don't know the official rationale, but the committee historically favored less drastic changes to the core language. So I guess that's inline with that. Adding a mechanism to truly undeclare things is uncharted territory, with potentially many pitfalls.

Comment: Why does it compile when we remove the `requires m > 1` from the second overload?

Comment: @Carucel - The requires clause is also part of the signature in a sense. Removing it also changes the signature.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, I really don't understand why C++ is designed like this. If we do `requires m > 1 && true` for the second overload, it does compile.

Comment: @Carucel - Yes, the expression changed again, thus changes the signature. It was like this with templates already, so that again is not something entirely new.

Comment: @t.niese: If an unsatisfied requirement unmade the declaration entirely, you’d have trouble defining the function outside the class.  That also explains why `&& true` helps: it lets such a definition be distinguished.